# NoteContext showing undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I create a Notecontext.  Then i created an useState of an array then i import it in Notes componante, to show title of that object array i wrote .map code.

but my code don't shoe result . it showes an error.

> ## This is my NoteContext in react where i create new context.

```
import { createContext } from "react";

const NoteContext = createContext();

export default NoteContext;
```

> ### then i created Notestate where i createa useState.

```
import NoteContext from "./NoteContext";import { useState } from "react";
```

```
const NoteState = (props) => {
```

```
const notesinitial = [
    {
        "_id": "64ec90f7007592ad08788d86",
        "user": "64e6057421a1b517d5a58edb",
        "title": "My Title",
        "description": "Make a desciplined life",
        "tage": "General",
        "date": "2023-08-28T12:20:07.092Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "64ec90f7007592ad08788d86",
        "user": "64e6057421a1b517d5a58edb",
        "title": "My Title",
        "description": "Make a desciplined life",
        "tage": "General",
        "date": "2023-08-28T12:20:07.092Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]
const [notes, setNotes] = useState(notesinitial)


return (
    
        <NoteContext.Provider value={{ notes, setNotes }}>
            {props.children}
        </NoteContext.Provider>
    
)
```

```
}export default NoteState;
```

> ### then import Notecontext in Notes componant and destructure the values of notes and setNotes .

```
import React, { useContext } from 'react' 
import NoteContext from "../context/notes/NoteContext"
```

```
export const Notes = () => {
const noteCtx = useContext(NoteContext);
console.log(noteCtx);
const { notes, setNotes } = noteCtx;
```

```
return (
    <div>
        <div className="container my-3">
            <h2>Your Notes</h2>
            {notes.map((note) => {
                return note.title;
            })}
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

```
}
```

```
export default Notes;
```

> ### but code showing this error

```
Notes.js:8 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'notes' of 'noteCtx' as it is undefined.
at Notes (Notes.js:8:1)at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js:20074:1)at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:21587:1)at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:27451:1)at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:26557:1)at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:26466:1)Notes @ Notes.js:8renderWithHooks @ react-dom.development.js:16305mountIndeterminateComponent @ react-dom.development.js:20074beginWork @ react-dom.development.js:21587callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4164invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ react-dom.development.js:4213invokeGuardedCallback @ react-dom.development.js:4277beginWork$1 @ react-dom.development.js:27451performUnitOfWork @ react-dom.development.js:26557workLoopSync @ react-dom.development.js:26466renderRootSync @ react-dom.development.js:26434recoverFromConcurrentError @ react-dom.development.js:25850performSyncWorkOnRoot @ react-dom.development.js:26096flushSyncCallbacks @ react-dom.development.js:12042flushSync @ react-dom.development.js:26201scheduleRoot @ react-dom.development.js:27810(anonymous) @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:284performReactRefresh @ react-refresh-runtime.development.js:263(anonymous) @ RefreshUtils.js:85setTimeout (async)enqueueUpdate @ RefreshUtils.js:83executeRuntime @ RefreshUtils.js:243$ReactRefreshModuleRuntime$ @ Notes.js:23./src/componants/Notes.js @ Notes.js:23options.factory @ react refresh:6webpack_require @ bootstrap:24_requireSelf @ hot module replacement:102apply @ jsonp chunk loading:407(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:344internalApply @ hot module replacement:342(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:279waitForBlockingPromises @ hot module replacement:233(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:277Promise.then (async)(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:276Promise.then (async)(anonymous) @ hot module replacement:256Promise.then (async)hotCheck @ hot module replacement:247check @ dev-server.js:14(anonymous) @ dev-server.js:69emit @ events.js:153reloadApp @ reloadApp.js:38warnings @ index.js:274(anonymous) @ socket.js:62client.onmessage @ WebSocketClient.js:45react-dom.development.js:18687 The above error occurred in the <Notes> component:
```

```
at Notes (http://localhost:3000/main.c8dd6a1f21a99316820a.hot-update.js:30:68)
at div
at Home
at RenderedRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40027:5)
at Routes (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40659:5)
at div
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:40597:15)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:38698:5)
at App
```

```
Consider adding an error boundary to your tree to customize error handling behavior.Visit https://reactjs.org/link/error-boundaries to learn more about error boundaries.
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you make the context with an empty value. try to set the values with undefined initially, like:

```
const NoteContext = createContext({ notes: undefined , setNotes: undefined  });
```

Comment: now it shows " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

Comment: I am not sure. but, did you wrap the App component or the parent component of Notes with the context provider. I mean the NoteState component as a context provider ?

Comment: No I didn't do it. Can you please show me how it can be done.

Comment: You need to go to index.js and wrap <App /> with NoteState like: 
    root.render(<NoteState><App /></NoteState>);  you can also watch these videos about [context](https://youtu.be/_ywG27YBNyQ?si=3fZIHdyHX_eN4GSL) [custom context provider](https://youtu.be/jIsgG2TI6d8?si=BJPJFTOaXaWQgIJ1) to get the whole information